# How to make a Turtle Longer

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

I am working on a Python Turtle Snake Program, and I want to make my Turtle longer.
By that, I mean that I increase the 1 Cube to 2 Cubes, then 3, etcetera, for my Snake Game.

Can you please inform how I could do that with turtle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I once made a game like that. You can just create more turtles and use them as the body. Make the first turtle as the head of the snake. Then whenever it eats food,run a function that will create another turtle as a body component and put it in the previous position of head component. Repeat this everytime the snake eats a food.
I am not so good in explaining,so sorry for any inconvenience : )